# I would like to make a wrap animation

Tags: animation

[image]

I would like to make a gif-like animation.

I tried using cloth physics, but I found it difficult to express the point where the cloth is in free fall and the vinyl is stretched.

If you have any recommendations for me, I would appreciate it if you could let me know.

---

I will post the YouTube that I referred to.

●Wrap ANYTHING in Plastic Procedurally in Blender - TUTORIAL
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gPyRRR1lLcg&ab_channel=Simon3D

●Create Motion Graphic Animations with the cloth modifier | blender tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IRYA69lWET0&ab_channel=3Dschool

[image]

Comment: i don't know how perfect it should be, but maybe just a plane with some hooks animated is the much easier way doing it....?

Comment: Sorry to be selfish, but I want to make it almost perfect. However, I don't need the expression at the end of the movie where the roll is stretched like rubber when pulled and then adheres to the roll.

I couldn't get the roll and Wrap to be close together using the shape keys method, and it was difficult to animate it using the shrink wrap modifier method.

I have added the YouTube link I used as a reference if you would like to see it.